# tomcat jdbc pool has some different behaviour about connection reuse

Tags: java, tomcat8, apache-commons-dbcp, tomcat-jdbc

I have configured Tomcat JDBC pool in my web application and added maven dependency with version 8.0.38 which is my tomcat version also. Now I get connection from that pool and check value of autoCommit property and it is "true" then I set that connection's autoCommit to "false". Then I commit the transaction, then close that connection. Now I get another connection from pool and check the value of autoCommit property and it was "false". But I was expecting it as true. I also use Apache Common DBCP2 pooling library, and that has not this kind of behaviour. Whenever I get connection from common DBCP2 pool, it return connection with autoCommit set to "true". I have tested and seen this behaviour of tomcat jdbc pool.

```
Connection con1 = basicDataSourceWrite.getConnection();
con1.setAutoCommit(false);
System.out.println(con1.getAutoCommit()+ " con1  " );
con1.commit();
con1.close();

Connection con2 = basicDataSourceWrite.getConnection();
System.out.println(con2.getAutoCommit()+ " con2  " );
```

Output of above code is

> false con1
>   false con2

```
<bean id="basicDataSourceWrite" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${mysqlEndpointWrite}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mysqlUserWrite}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mysqlPasswordWrite}" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="4" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
</bean>
```

here setting defaultAutoCommit to "true" even not work for me. it always return connection with autoCoomit false.

So I want to know how common DBCP2 manage this and how to achieve this in tomcat JDBC pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://coderanch.com/t/583969/databases/Tomcat-connection-pool-auto-commit) (or rather a feature since it hasn't been fixed) of Tomcat JDBC.

Setting the value of `defaultAutoCommit` isn't enough, you also need to enable [interceptors](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors) which will actually enforce those settings. This will make the `defaultAutoCommit` value affect the connections.

```
<property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="ConnectionState" />
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. Adding interceptor solve the problem.